# 3D surface plot with axis inside plot

Tags: pgfplots, positioning

I try to draw the energy surface of a magnetic particle. For this i want the axis system to come from the inside of the particles pointing to the ouside. Ist ist basically the example below, but with the z axis inside of the cone.

```
    \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      axis on top,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
      domain=0:1,
      y domain=0:2*pi,
      xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
      ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=0.0,
      mesh/interior colormap=
        {blueblack}{color=(black) color=(blue)},
      colormap/blackwhite, 
      samples=10,
      samples y=40,
      z buffer=sort,
     ]
      \addplot3[surf] 
        ({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{x});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

To clearify: The second image shows a plot of the crystal energy of a magnetic nanoparticle. The crystalaxis should now come from the center of the particle to the outside, leaving the surface at the red area. But because PGFplots draws the axis lines in the background the optic result is not so nice.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Maybe you'll need to add more details about what exactly you want to achieve... What do you mean "inside"? Do you want the cone to be rotated so that the axis belongs to its surface? If it is hard to put into word, maybe you could add an illustration (either another picture about the same topic or simply a hand-drawn mockup).

Comment: Hey, thank your for your answer. What I want to achieve is that the axis is not in front or behind the surface but really inside of the plot. Meaning behind the grey area but in front of the blue area. In other words it should be the rotational axis of the plotted cone.

Comment: Oh, so the only problem is that the grey part should "hide" the axis?

Comment: @T.Verron I think that Matthias wants the `z`-axis to be cropped by the plot. That is, the front of the cone should obscure the axis until the axis pops out the top over the blue background of the interior of the cone. Seems like a reasonable request - but I don't know how to do it:(.

Comment: @ T.Verron. Yes that is exactly what i meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this should be possible using layers in `pgfplots`, but I couldn't figure it out. Here is a brute force solution in which you draw the back half separate from the front half by setting different limits for your `y domain`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=none,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
      domain=0:1,
      y domain=0:pi,
      xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
      ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=0.0, zmax=1.5,
      mesh/interior colormap=
        {blueblack}{color=(black) color=(yellow)},
      colormap/blackwhite, 
      samples=10,
      samples y=20,
      z buffer=sort,
     ]
      \addplot3[surf] 
        ({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{x});
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
      domain=0:1,
      y domain=pi:2*pi,
      xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
      ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=0.0, zmax=1.5,
      mesh/interior colormap=
        {blueblack}{color=(black) color=(yellow)},
      colormap/blackwhite, 
      samples=10,
      samples y=20,
      z buffer=sort,
     ]
      \addplot3[surf] 
        ({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{x});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The z ordering of axis lines versus the surface is due to a limitation of `pgfplots`. Consequently, the solution is the only valid one for the time being. Alternatives would be to use (semi) boxed axis lines instead of centered ones.